# How to do API throttling in pig or hive UDF?

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I have some data could process in pig or hive. For a particular field I need to call another API for processing. I want to limit the rate of that API call under a certain threshold, but didn't find any document talking about this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ways to accomplish that.
You can control the number of tasks from that job and throttle each task but that would only control one job.  Once you have more than one job running, you'll be hitting the API more...